# What is the difference between __geo_interface__ and to_json()?

Tags: geojson, geopandas, geemap

I'm using geopandas extensively in my scripts and one of my colleague shown me the `to_json()` method. I was using the `__geo_interface__` magic method previously and sometime the `to_json()` is not compatible with other tools like the GEE API:

using a geopandas dataframe, this doesn't work:

```py
import geemap

gdf_ee = geemap.geojson_to_ee(gdf.to_json())
```

and this work:

```py
import geemap

gdf_ee = geemap.geojson_to_ee(gdf.__geo_interface__)
```

According to the doc both are returning GeoJson, so can someone explain me the difference or lead me to the appropriate documentation ?

Comment: See if it helps : https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756 (QGIS has it too now)

Comment: it's actually super usefull to better understand `__geo_interface__` but any guess for the `to_json` ?

Comment: the code / help of the function ? : https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/85e066a5c7c3ec9ad7bebc254b964a34053fcf65/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [J. Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93097/j-monticolo) for the guidance, According to the documentations ([**geo_interface**](https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756) and [to_json](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/85e066a5c7c3ec9ad7bebc254b964a34053fcf65/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L673)), they are not the exactly the same.

### __geo_interface__

Uses the following keys:

- type (required)
- bbox (optional)
- properties (optional)
- geometry (optional)
- coordinates (required)

and return a json dict

## to_json

Returns a GeoJSON representation of the `GeoDataFrame` as a **string**.